# Pathauto tokens for taxonomy terms except root

Tags: 8, path-aliases, tokens

Thanks to the Pathauto module and tokens, it is very easy to generate URLs with *[node:field_product_category:entity:parents:join-path]/[node:field_product_category:entity]/[node:title]*, but I would like to start at the 2nd level.

Is it possible to exclude the root level from *[node:field_product_category:entity:parents:join-path]*?

Instead of `http://www.example.com/redundant_root_category/category_from_level_2/category_from_level_3/super_product`, I would like to get `http://www.example.com/category_from_level_2/category_from_level_3/super_product`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default tokens won't allow you to do this, but the only thing you're missing I think is an array token that removes the first element, I'd call it "tail". See token_token_info(), which defines for example a 'reversed and other array tokens:

```
$info['tokens']['array']['reversed'] = array(
  'name' => t('Reversed'),
  'description' => t('The array reversed.'),
'type' => 'array',
);
```

And the implementation for that is in token_tokens():

```
// [array:reversed:*] chained tokens.
if ($reversed_tokens = \Drupal::token()->findWithPrefix($tokens, 'reversed')) {
  $replacements += \Drupal::token()->generate('array', $reversed_tokens, array('array' => array_reverse($array, TRUE)), array('array sort' => FALSE) + $options, $bubbleable_metadata);
}
```

Instead of array_reverse(), you'd call array_shift() on the array first and then pass that along.

Might also be a useful standard token to have in the token.module, if someone wants to provide a patch.

Your token would then look like this:

```
[node:field_product_category:entity:parents:tail:join-path]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom module. I made this module for a Drupal 10 site I'm developing and my quick tests show it working. For this example we'll name our custom module *all_but_first_token_modifier*

1. Create dir `/web/modules/custom/all_but_first_token_modifier`. All subsequent steps are inside of this directory.
2. Create file `all_but_first_token_modifier.info.yml` with this content:

   ```yml
   name: All But First Array Token Modifier
   type: module
   description: 'Token modifier to get the array of items without the first element'
   package: All But First Array Token Modifier
   core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9 || ^10
   dependencies:
     - token:token
   ```
3. Create file `all_but_first_token_modifier.module` with this content:

   ```php
   <?php
   use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
   use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;

   function all_but_first_token_modifier_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
     switch ($route_name) {
       // Main module help for the custom_token module.
       case 'help.page.all_but_first_token_modifier':
         $output = '';
         $output .= '<h3>' . t('About') . '</h3>';
         $output .= '<p>' . t('Custom token module to get the array without the first element') . '</p>';
         return $output;

       default:
     }
   }


   function all_but_first_token_modifier_token_info() {

     $info['tokens']['array']['all_but_first'] = array(
       'name' => t('All But First'),
       'description' => t('The array without the first element.'),
       'type' => 'array',
     );

     return $info;
   }

   function all_but_first_token_modifier_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, \Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
     $replacements=[];
     // Array tokens.
     if ($type == 'array' && !empty($data['array']) && is_array($data['array'])) {
       $array = $data['array'];

       //$sort = isset($options['array sort']) ? $options['array sort'] : TRUE;
       //$keys = token_element_children($array, $sort);

       /** @var \Drupal\Core\Render\RendererInterface $renderer */
       $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');

       foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
         switch ($name) {
           case 'all_but_first':
             $all_but_first = array_slice($array,1);
             $replacements[$original] = token_render_array($all_but_first, $options);
             break;
         }
       }

       // [array:all_but_first:*] chained tokens.
       if ($all_but_first_tokens = \Drupal::token()->findWithPrefix($tokens, 'all_but_first')) {
         $replacements += \Drupal::token()->generate('array', $all_but_first_tokens, ['array' => array_slice($array,1)], ['array sort' => FALSE] + $options, $bubbleable_metadata);
       }

     }


     return $replacements;
   }
   ```
4. Enable the module in your Drupal admin interface and you'll now have an additional option for array tokens. It can be used the same as the reverse token modifier. Example: `[term:parents:all_but_first:join-path]`