# How do I vary PathAuto paths based on a field?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have a field type called "Venue". If the Venue is in the US, I want the path to be:

```
/CITY/my-venue
```

But if it's in any other country, the path must be:

```
/AU/CITY/my-venue
```

In other words, non-US venues must get their country code appended to the front.

Is this even possible with the current PathAuto module? Or how can one do this?

Comment: I imagine you're going to have to create a simple module with a hook - i've done a similar thing. You can still utilise `pathauto` for generating the aliases, using the `pathauto.alias_cleaner` service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to define a custom token using [hook_token_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_token_info/8.2.x) and [hook_tokens()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_tokens/8.2.x). Based on the venue, you either return the country code or nothing. If the token has no value, pathauto will automatically clean it up and drop that part.

[Pathauto tokens for taxonomy terms except root](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225694/pathauto-tokens-for-taxonomy-terms-except-root) for example has some hints on how to implement custom tokens.

Answer (score -1):

> Follow these steps (first enable token module):
>
> 1. go to Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases > Patterns
> 2. select "Pattern type" as "content"
> 3. Add "Path pattern" (Click on "Browse available tokens" and select fields from token list.)
> 4. You can choose " Content type"
> 5. Add label.
>    6 Save.